# VFP App gets This app can't run on your PC running Terminal Services on Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, visual-foxpro, terminal-services

I've got a VFP 9 SP2 app that is running on a Windows 2012 server via Terminal Services.

Sporadically the users will get the message "This app can't run on your PC".

Any idea what causes this? This is a 32-bit app running on a 64-bit server. We've tried setting the shortcut to run in compatibility mode for WinXP SP3 and it still has this problem.

Usually rebooting the server will fix this, but surely there has to be a configuration solution?

Comment: We have run VFP9 SP2 on 2012 over Terminal Services with no problems.  What's the exact message?

Comment: The exact message is a blue bar across the middle of the screen that says "This app can't run on your PC To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher" Here's a link to a screenshot: [link](http://sherware.com/download/cantrun.png) @LAK

Comment: Hmm, we've never seen that before.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Is anything written to the Windows Event Log?